# Running DB2 Queries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code, db2

How can I run a DB2 query inside Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Who will write the extension? At the present date, I don't find any offering.  IBM only supplies a vsc extension to allow access to the bluemix CLI. But that may not help for on-prem Db2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an extension for IBM DB2 in VS Code. You can find instructions for installation and use at this link.

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/justin-sobieski/2019/05/21/vscode-extension-for-db2